# How to update Table 1 from Table 2 when they have nothing in common?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have 2 tables - each has a single row only.  I want to update o1 and o2 columns on Table1 with the corresponding columns in Table2.

```
create table Table1(c1 int, c2 int, o1 int, o2 int)
create table Table2(o1 int, o2 int)
```

I have the following, which is horrible (but works).

```
update Table1
set o1 = (select o1 from Table2),
    o2 = (select o2 from Table2)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Actually that's the canonical way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
update table1
    set o1 = t2.o1,
        o2 = t2.o2
from table2 t2;
```

Comment: What if there was Table3 with column o3 - that I wanted to update as well?  Would I list both table2 and table3 in the from statement?  (having trouble making that work).

Comment: did you mean `set` instead of `where`?  Maybe it's syntax I'm unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 1):

By this way, you can do as expected, even if there were 1 or 'n' rows-

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.o1 = T2.o1,
    T1.o2 = T2.o2
from table1 T1 INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON T1.o1=T2.o1 AND T1.o2=T2.o2;
```